# Ajax dont answer me the true condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the html div:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable feedstatus hidden">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" style="color:#0c0; font-size:40px;"> </span></a><br/>Message recieved.<br/>Thanks <strong class="feedbacker"></strong> 
                        </div>
                        <form role="form" onsubmit="regFeedback()">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control bordering" id="feedbacker" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" style="border:none; border:0px solid #fff;" required/><br>
                                <input class="form-control bordering" id="feedbackemail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="tu@email.com" style="border:none; border:0px solid #fff;"  required/><br>
                                <textarea class="form-control bordering" id="feedback" name="feedback" placeholder="Write me something before go" style="border:none; border:0px solid #fff;"  required/></textarea><br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

In the other hand, the javascript:

```
function regFeedback() {
var name=document.getElementById('feedbacker').value;
var mail=document.getElementById('feedbackemail').value;
var feed=document.getElementById('feedback').value;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("form").remove();
           $(".feedstatus").removeClass("hidden");
           $(".feedbacker").text(name);
           alert("Mensaje recibido. Gracias");
       });
   }
   };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","https://page.php?name="+name+"&email="+mail+"&feedback="+feed,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
   }
```

The data arrive to the data base, but the callback event where verifies: "if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {" looks like don't work. I'm new in this, but i made it work well. But from a moment editing to another, something is wrong :/

Comment: is url passed in ajax is correct ? `https://page.php`

Comment: What .. Why are you using jquery and core js mixed??

Comment: @AhmedGinani of course is not..

Comment: maybe you should use jquery ajax instead of native it's much easier to understand.

Comment: `https://page.php?` I think your url isn't correct

Comment: You mean where a put the 'alert()'? @M A SIDDIQUI

Comment: No @Ahmed Ginani, i change it by security reasons. I have it well and the it saves the data. The trouble is in the answer after data saved: the jquery inside the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I think instead of

```
 if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
```

will be

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
```

`this` is a keyword in javascript & it refers to an object; that is, the subject in context, or the subject of the executing code

Also it is surprising so see the `document.ready` function is inside ajax success function

Comment: Let me check. Thanks :3

Comment: @Greg remove the document.ready function but only keep the code

Comment: Done! @brk. Thanks

Comment: @Greg does my answer helped you ?

Comment: I assume it's better to use 'xmlhttp' instead 'this' is better, thanks. But the trouble contunues :/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable feedstatus hidden">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" style="color:#0c0; font-size:40px;"> </span></a><br/>Message recieved.<br/>Thanks <strong class="feedbacker"></strong> 
    </div>
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control bordering" id="feedbacker" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" style="border:none; border:0px solid #fff;" required/><br>
            <input class="form-control bordering" id="feedbackemail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="tu@email.com" style="border:none; border:0px solid #fff;"  required/><br>
            <textarea class="form-control bordering" id="feedback" name="feedback" placeholder="Write me something before go" style="border:none; border:0px solid #fff;"  required/></textarea><br>
            <button type="button" onclick="regFeedback()" class="btn btn-block">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: **You are using button as submit, use this as a button and call javascript at button onclick
    Replace your Html code with this:**

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your **xmlhttp** object while checking for state change instead of this.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {       
       $("form").remove();
       $(".feedstatus").removeClass("hidden");
       $(".feedbacker").text(name);
       alert("Mensaje recibido. Gracias");       
}
};
```

Also you are not require to perform action on **$(document).ready()** function, you can perform actions directly in success block.

Comment: Done! But not. Thanks

Comment: What issue are you getting now?

Comment: The same although all you answers guys

Comment: Please check browser's log, then you will be more close to the issue.

Comment: I have too long watching it and no idea. I will paste it.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://page?parameters. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://page.000webhostapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: This error means, you are trying to access pages from different protocol. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work for more information on that.

Comment: Nishesh Pratap
nishesh.pratap@gmail.com
Hello
09/05/17
04:23

Comment: As your website is hosted with **http://** protocol and you are using **https://** in your ajax url, that is the issue change it to **`http://greg`**

Comment: Oh right works!!! :D ... Thanks \n ---
But i remember i had secure http before, i will check that T.T